# different hover and selected states for a spry menu bar

Tags: spry

anyone out there know how to make different hover and selected states for tabs within the same spry tabbed menu?

im having a lot of trouble....

Answer (score 0):

if you mean their styles you can simply edit its related CSS file and make any style you need